# How to prevent Angular form from being sent to a php file (method="post") when invalid?

Tags: php, angularjs, forms

I guess in such case the default of Angular would be to add ng-disabled to submit button. If so, the user could be warned about the errors in each input, but the errors would be shown instantly. Is there a way to show the errors (through function in controller or other way), only after onclick, without having the form actually submitted and send to php if it is invalid?

Comment: There is extensive documentation on the subject, which is too broad to cover in a single answer: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
   <form name="myForm">
         <input type="text" name="textField" ng-model="textField"/>
         <md-button type="button"
                    class="btn-width-medium md-raised md-primary" 
                    ng-click="validateForm()">
                Save
         </md-button>
    </form
```

**Controller :**

```
.controller("controller",function($scope){
   $scope.validateForm = function(){
      // Do validation here
      // If valid 
         // Submit form - post data
      // Else invalid
         // Show message and return
   };
});
```

Comment: Yes, I know about this way, but doing it like that You can't call the function that will check the form and show the errors. I want to actually click the button (even when there are errors) to check the form for errors and show them, but without submitting the form (taking post action to a php file) if the form is invalid.

Comment: if you want to check for errors after submitting remove submit attribute from form. I am updating my answer check that.

Comment: Thank You, that's a good point. However, how to trigger submit in the validateForm function only when the form is valid ? According to the docks: ngSubmit "prevents the default action (which for form means sending the request to the server and reloading the current page), but only if the form does not contain action" so  ngSubmit won't work altogether with action="something.php" in the same form.

Comment: Thanks happy to help :-)